# How to correctly implement ExpressCheckout in cakePHP 3.x?

Tags: cakephp, paypal

I've implemented ExpressCheckoutDG in cakePHP3.x website, based on the ExpressCheckout Wizard. (https://devtools-paypal.com/integrationwizard/)

So the payment procedure is realized in a dedicated opened frame.

Everything goes well until payment is achived and Paypal call the return URL.
At the end of the called method named confirm, I don't know what to do to close the Paypal frame and go back to a specified url.

My confirm method is:

```
public function confirm() {

    $this->log($this->request->url . ' confirm', 'debug' );

    $this->loadModel('Orders');

    $PaymentOption = "PayPal";
    if ( $PaymentOption == "PayPal" )
    {
        $res = $this->GetExpressCheckoutDetails( $_REQUEST['token'] );

        /**
         * I removed this part of code as it doesn't concern the problem
         */

        $resArray = $this->ConfirmPayment ( $token, $paymentType, $currencyCodeType, $payerID, $finalPaymentAmount, $items );
        $ack = strtoupper($resArray["ACK"]);

        $this->log($this->request->url . ' confirm :' . $ack, 'debug' );

        if( $ack == "SUCCESS" || $ack == "SUCCESSWITHWARNING" )
        {

            /**
             * I removed this part of code as it doesn't concern the problem
             */

            /*
             * Here I save the transaction
             */

            // Add javascript to close Digital Goods frame. You may want to add more javascript code to
            // display some info message indicating status of purchase in the parent window
            $this->Flash->success(__("transaction successfully completed"));

            $this->log($this->request->url . ' confirm : display confirm.ctp', 'debug' );

            /*
             * So the problem is here: What to do to close the Paypal frame, AND return to a given page of my website??
             */
            //$this->redirect(['controller' => 'Sites', 'action' => 'view']);
            $this->set(compact('ack'));
        }
        else
        {
            //Display a user friendly Error on the page using any of the following error information returned by PayPal
            $ErrorCode = urldecode($resArray["L_ERRORCODE0"]);
            $ErrorShortMsg = urldecode($resArray["L_SHORTMESSAGE0"]);
            $ErrorLongMsg = urldecode($resArray["L_LONGMESSAGE0"]);
            $ErrorSeverityCode = urldecode($resArray["L_SEVERITYCODE0"]);

            echo "DoExpressCheckoutDetails API call failed. ";
            echo "Detailed Error Message: " . $ErrorLongMsg;
            echo "Short Error Message: " . $ErrorShortMsg;
            echo "Error Code: " . $ErrorCode;
            echo "Error Severity Code: " . $ErrorSeverityCode;

            $this->Flash->error(__("votre achat n'a pas été accepté"));
            $this->set(compact('ack'));
        }
    }
    $this->set(compact('ack'));
}
```

As you can see, the payment process goes well until trying to finish:

```
2015-02-20 11:00:38 Debug: pros/Sitemessages/checkout checkout
2015-02-20 11:00:38 Debug: pros/Sitemessages/checkout SetExpressCheckoutDG
2015-02-20 11:00:38 Debug: pros/Sitemessages/checkout hash_call
2015-02-20 11:00:41 Debug: pros/Sitemessages/checkout deformatNVP
2015-02-20 11:00:41 Debug: pros/Sitemessages/checkout deformatNVP
2015-02-20 11:00:41 Debug: pros/Sitemessages/checkout hash_call: closing
2015-02-20 11:00:41 Debug: pros/Sitemessages/checkout RedirectToPayPalDG
2015-02-20 11:01:15 Debug: pros/Sitemessages/confirm confirm
2015-02-20 11:01:15 Debug: pros/Sitemessages/confirm GetExpressCheckoutDetails
2015-02-20 11:01:15 Debug: pros/Sitemessages/confirm hash_call
2015-02-20 11:01:18 Debug: pros/Sitemessages/confirm deformatNVP
2015-02-20 11:01:18 Debug: pros/Sitemessages/confirm deformatNVP
2015-02-20 11:01:18 Debug: pros/Sitemessages/confirm hash_call: closing
2015-02-20 11:01:18 Debug: pros/Sitemessages/confirm ConfirmPayment
2015-02-20 11:01:18 Debug: pros/Sitemessages/confirm hash_call
2015-02-20 11:01:23 Debug: pros/Sitemessages/confirm deformatNVP
2015-02-20 11:01:23 Debug: pros/Sitemessages/confirm deformatNVP
2015-02-20 11:01:23 Debug: pros/Sitemessages/confirm hash_call: closing
2015-02-20 11:01:23 Debug: pros/Sitemessages/confirm confirm :SUCCESS
2015-02-20 11:01:23 Notice: pros/Sitemessages/confirm transaction successfully saved
2015-02-20 11:01:23 Debug: pros/Sitemessages/confirm confirm : display confirm.ctp
```

here is my confirm.ctp file:

```
<?php if ( $ack == "SUCCESS" || $ack == "SUCCESSWITHWARNING" ):?>
    <script>
    alert("Payment Successful");
    // add relevant message above or remove the line if not required
    window.onload = function(){
        if(window.opener){
             window.close();
         }
        else{
             if(top.dg.isOpen() == true){
                 top.dg.closeFlow();
                 return true;
              }
          }
    };

    </script>
<?php else:?>
    <script>
    alert("Payment failed");
    // add relevant message above or remove the line if not required
    window.onload = function(){
        if(window.opener){
             window.close();
         }
        else{
             if(top.dg.isOpen() == true){
                 top.dg.closeFlow();
                 return true;
              }
          }
    };

    </script>
<?php endif;?>
```

Any idea on the solution to close the Paypal Frame and go back to a given url?

Answer (score 1):

You need to have a page with nothing on it except for the javascript to close the window.  That's what you would set as your return URL and your cancel URL, so that the window simply closes.

[Here's a demo](http://paypal.angelleye.com/temp/paypal-php-express-checkout-digital-goods-demo.zip) I put together using my [PHP class library for PayPal](https://www.angelleye.com/product/php-class-library-paypal/) that will show you how to make it work.

Comment: Hello Andrew, I realize that I forgot to add this piece of code in my post but confirm .ctp is the page set by returnUrl, and called by Paypal. So maybe I could remove the if statement, in case...

Comment: Even without the if statement, Paypal window is still here and displays "Waiting for mywebsite..."

Comment: Thanks Andrew, you were right, may page was in fact not empty because of the default layout included bt cake.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I found my mistake.
I had to add the following line at the begining of the ctp file.

`<?php $this->layout=false?>`